# Why is there extra whitespace at the beginning of my file after I write it with PHP?

Tags: php, html, fopen

I am trying to make a PHP script which creates a file and adds headers into that file but the file must be PHP code only, with nothing before the PHP tags.

But for some reason, the script is adding an extra blank line and it does not work. I know this because when I manually edited it and removed the line it worked. Here is the script:

```
$stringData = "<?php\n
header('Content-type: audio/mp3');\n
\n
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$name\"');\n
readfile(\"$name.mp3\");\n
?>";

$myFile = "matt/$name/download.php";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: This looks like a bit of a weird construction to me. You may want to look into `mod_rewrite` URLs that allow requests to be redirected to one central PHP file. Where are you getting an error and what exactly does it say? Also, the `\n` in the file are unnecessary, you already have them implicitly through the line break

Comment: It's not going to help fix your problem but have you ever heard of a thing called punctuation?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better idea to store the file to download in the session or in a request variable (`$_GET` or `$_POST`) rather than writing out a separate download.php for each file?  Of course, this means your download.php would have to do more security checks.

Comment: I had the same issue as I was unable to trace the tailing space before xml file output I did sth simple I put the content before the header in between `ob_start();....ob_end_clean();` and it solved my issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the blank line? If it's at the end of the file, the simplest solution is to remove the closing `?>`.

It is actually considered a best practice by many to omit the closing PHP tag in files that are meant to include only PHP code.

Or, as an alternative, have you tried `file_put_contents()`?

#### update

There is no obvious way the code you've posted could result in leading whitespace; Passing `'w'` to `fopen` truncates the file and you have no leading whitespace in the content you are writing afterwards.  When I run your code, I get the desired output with no leading whitespace (and duplicate newlines as noted by codeaddict):

```
<?php

header('Content-type: audio/mp3');



header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test"');

readfile("test.mp3");

?>
```

Comment: I think what the problem was is that i had a line break before the `<?php` and when i fixed it google chrome was loading a cached version thanks though this worked great

Comment: @Matthew What did, `file_put_contents`? That's very odd, as it should have been identical to the `fopen` code you were using

Comment: @MC *Worked like a charm* means you are supposed to accept that answer (and maybe even up-vote it if you like...). Btw, how do you know the line was before or after the `<php` tag? It is very likely it was after the closing `?>`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `\n` and also writing the contents on different lines, hence creating two newlines.

Example:

```
echo "a\n
b";
```

Will print

```
a

b
```

Remove either the `\n` or the line breaks to fix this.

Comment: I don't think the code you've shown us can do that. please cross check.

Comment: well when i visit the site it throws an error and when i manually open it in Dreamweaver there is a line break before the first tag.